# Customize contextmenu (html/javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm a bit confused about the documentation I'm seeing at these two locations:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contextmenu
and
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/contextmenu.html

Both of the above sites are pretty well respected but at least one claims that customizing the contextmenu is possible.  I'm looking to build my own right click menu, but was thinking I could just add things to the native context menu.

The closest site I could find, and most likely something I will do is posted here:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/07/25/using-jquery-to-create-a-right-click-function-to-save-website-logo/

Is the MDN site just wrong?  I didn't want to go and change that page without at least someone else acknowledging that it's almost completely wrong.  I also created a jsFiddle to make sure it wasn't a strange iFrame issue on the MDN site:

```
<body contextmenu="share">
  <menu type="context" id="share">
  <menu label="share">
  <menuitem label="Twitter" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hurray! I am learning ContextMenu from MDN via Mozilla');"></menuitem>
  <menuitem label="Facebook" onclick="window.open('https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Using_HTML_context_menus');"></menuitem>
</menu>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kikketer/cky0oz1f/

I tested on IE10, Chrome 39 mac/windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into [this feature's support list](http://caniuse.com/#feat=menu), you can see that only Firefox has partial support for it. Disabling or customizing the context menu can be considered an anti-pattern, in my humble opinion.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, wasn't sure if the three sites were speaking to the same functionality.  I did confirm that it's working as described in Firefox.  I think I'll just update the MDN page.  Disabling the context menu is handy when you want to provide right click menu of your own (say a game of sorts).  Customizing it seemed like a bonus.

Comment: There are a number of websites that have a context menu on right click. It makes me assume there is a way, just not the one you provided. Good luck with that ;)

Comment: There is a way, I was really just asking if the documentation was right or if I was reading something wrong.  I found that I can stop the "contextmenu" event from completing but still needed to sniff the button press to actually display something myself.